# Given one endpoint and midpoint in (x,y) of a line segment, explain how to find the other end point.

Tags: analytic-geometry

A line segment with one end at C(6,5)has midpoint M(4,2). Determine the coordinates of the other endpoint, D. Explain your solution and describe a method to check your answer.

Comment: Do you know the midpoint formula?

Comment: M=x1+x2/2,y1+y2/2 if you know how to solve the question please do so and with all steps.

Comment: So, use this formula With the coordinate of $M$ (mid point) and of $D$ ($x_1,y_1$) and find the coordinates of $D=(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: Please solve it and show all the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very very simple:

The midpoint formula give you:
$$
M=(x_m,y_m)=\left( \dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2},\dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)
$$
where $(x_1,y_1)$ are the coordinates of a point, say your $C$, and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinate of the oter point, i.e the point $D$ that you are searching.

So, substituting the given coordinates you have:

$$
4=\dfrac{6+x_2}{2} \quad \land \quad 2=\dfrac{5+y_2}{2}
$$
Now can you solve these two simple equations?

---

$$
4\cdot 2=6+x_2 \Rightarrow 8-6=x_2 \Rightarrow x_2=2
$$
$$
2 \cdot 2=5+y_2 \Rightarrow 4-5=y_2 \Rightarrow y_2=-1
$$

Comment: How can you solve these two simple equations? Can you please finish, with steps.

Comment: Don't you know how solve a linear equation such these?

Comment: Would you please do it I'm not sure . I'm a grade 8 student doing grade 10 work without a teacher.

Comment: See my edit. But you have to do some work... And not forget to accept the answer!